# Form in html is not redirecting to php

Tags: php, html, forms

Website source:http://www.salefee.com/

Can someone checkout my above mentioned site..I have made a form under "To recieve the salefee story ebook,submit your email id"

I have made a form in which user submits his email id,then form is linked to a php file which sends email to user email id. 
THE PROBLEM IS THAT FORM IS NOT BIENG REDIRECTED TO .php FILE. I have added `action` and `method` attribute in HTML form. The php code is not being executed when user clicks submit button.

The code of HTML is as follows:

```
    <!-- Mailchimp Newsletter -->
              <div style="text-align:center">  
              <div class="newsletter-wrapper animateblock rtl-2 speed-1">
                <form action="story.php" method="post" class="form-inline subscription-mailchimp">
                  <div class="form-group input-group input-newsletter">
                    <input class="form-control" id="newsletter-email" name="newsletter-email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
                  <small class="help-block">Don't worry. We do not spam :)</small>
              </div>
              </div>
<!-- End Mailchimp Newsletter -->
```

My php code named as story.php is as follows:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $to_email = "salefee12@gmail.com" //Recipient email, Replace with own email here


  //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
  $user_trial_email   = filter_var($_POST["newsletter-email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //additional php validation
  if (!filter_var($user_trial_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email.'));
    die($output);
  }

  //subject
  $subject = "The Story";

  //email body
  $message_body = "Email  : ".$user_trial_email."\r\nApp link:https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.salefee.salefee.salefee\r\nWe will shortly send you the whole story";

  //proceed with PHP email.
  $headers = 'From: '."salefee12@gmail.com".''."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$user_trial_email.''."\r\n".
  'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

  $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

  if (!$send_mail)
  {
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
  } else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_trial_name.', Thank you for subscribing. You will soon get a link to download app.'));
    die($output);
  }
}
?>
```

Can someone help me out with this code...Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'd change `if ($_POST)` to `if (isset($_POST["newsletter-email"]))` because $_POST is a superglobal and does not return true. It returns an array.

Comment: Don't tag questions with PHPMailer if you're not using it (though perhaps you should).

Comment: Do you have any logs? Looking at your code, the php file should be in the same folder as your HTML. Is it the case?

Comment: <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to give name to your submit button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

And then in your php file:

```
if (isset($_POST("submit")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP:**

```
if ($_POST['signup']) {
//your script which you want to execute as soon as form submitted
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
```

Read more about how to use $_POST[]

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP data is passed by name not id. So your HTML code should look like this

`<input class="form-control" id="newsletter-email" **name**="newsletter-email" name="newsletter-email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">`

And then your PHP file should work if you get data like this

```
$_POST["newsletter-email"]
```